# Selenium webdriver c# waiting for text to appear

Tags: c#, testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I wish to achieve the

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@id='timeLeft']"), "Time left: 7 seconds"));
```

function in c#, to wait for a text to appear. However, the `textToBePresentInElementLocated()` is only available in java. Is there a simple way to achieve this in c# , waiting for text to appear on page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is open source, so take a look at what it does:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.java#L305

You have the power of LINQ however, so it's going to be a little simpler, pseudo:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleReferenceException)); // ignore stale exception issues
wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='timeLeft']")).Text.Contains("Time left: 7 seconds"));
```

The last line will wait until the text returned from `d.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='timeLeft']")).Text` contains `Time left: 7 seconds`.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to resolve this issue by:

```
element = driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//div[@id='timeLeft']")));
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.TextToBePresentInElement(name, "Time left: 7 seconds"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I have Java version of my method for waiting text to be present in element.
Maybe it will help you.

```
public void waitForText(WebDriver driver, String text, By selector) {
    try {
        WebDriverWait waitElem = new WebDriverWait(driver, WAIT_TIME);
        waitElem.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(selector, text));
    }catch (TimeoutException e){
        logger.error(e.toString());
    }
}
```

Method takes instance of webdriver, String to mach text and Element declared in [By Class](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html) format.
WAIT_TIME is constant for wait time in seconds.

Answer (score -3):

To wait for Text to appear

```
  do
  {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
  }

  while(!driver.FindElement(ByXpath("//The Xpath of the TEXT//")).Displayed);

  {

  }
```